# OpenTelemetry Collector not exporting data to OTEL/HTTP exporter

Tags: docker, open-telemetry, zipkin, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I am using the example from here

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-docs/tree/main/otlp/docker

I have modified the OTEL config and now it looks like this. I have added otelhttp and otel exporter configuration.

### OTEL Configuration

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
        grpc:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans"
    format: proto

  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

# Alternatively, use jaeger_thrift_http with the settings below. In this case
# update the list of exporters on the traces pipeline.
#
#  jaeger_thrift_http:
#    url: http://jaeger-all-in-one:14268/api/traces

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, jaeger, otlp, otlphttp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus, otlp, otlphttp]
```

and I have a exporter running at port 4318 on localhost and OTEL setup is deployed using docker-compose using below docker compose file

### Docker Compose

```
version: "2"
services:

  # Jaeger
  jaeger-all-in-one:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268"
      - "14250:14250"

  # Zipkin
  zipkin-all-in-one:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"

  # Collector
  otel-collector:
    image: ${OTELCOL_IMG}
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config-demo.yaml", "${OTELCOL_ARGS}"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config-demo.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config-demo.yaml
    ports:
      - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
      - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
      - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
      - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
      - "4317:4317"   # otlp receiver
      - "8000:8000"   # parseable exporter
      - "4318:4318"
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-all-in-one
      - zipkin-all-in-one
    environment:
      OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

### On exporter side

(written in Rust) I am seeing this error

```
[2023-06-01T22:29:27Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Request parse error: Invalid HTTP version specified
[2023-06-01T22:29:27Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Request parse error: Invalid HTTP version specified
```

### On OTEL Collector side

I am seeing these errors

```
2023-06-01 23:29:27 }. Err: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"     {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-01 23:29:27 2023-06-01T22:29:27.409Z    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:195  [core] [Channel #5 SubChannel #6] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "Addr": "docker.for.mac.localhost:4318",
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "ServerName": "docker.for.mac.localhost:4318",
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "Attributes": null,
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "BalancerAttributes": null,
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "Type": 0,
2023-06-01 23:29:27   "Metadata": null
2023-06-01 23:29:27 }. Err: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"     {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-01 23:29:28 2023-06-01T22:29:28.405Z    info    jaegerexporter@v0.78.0/exporter.go:173  State of the connection with the Jaeger Collector backend     {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger", "state": "READY"}
```

I suspect OTLP Collector is making and HTTP/2 call which makes it fail.

### EDIT 1

I tried removing otlphttp completely from configuration and still got same errors on both exporter and collector side.

#### On Exporter

```
[2023-06-02T07:26:54Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Request parse error: Invalid HTTP version specified
[2023-06-02T07:26:54Z ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Request parse error: Invalid HTTP version specified
```

#### On Collector

```
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     | 2023-06-02T07:26:54.482Z      warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:195 [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "Addr": "docker.for.mac.localhost:4318",
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "ServerName": "docker.for.mac.localhost:4318",
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "Attributes": null,
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "BalancerAttributes": null,
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "Type": 0,
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     |   "Metadata": null
2023-06-02 08:26:54 docker-otel-collector-1     | }. Err: connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large"      {"grpc_log": true}
```

### EDIT 2

When I only configured otlphttp and removed otlp config section. Then there was no effect at all.
Neither collector sent anything nor exporter received anything.
My latest configuration looks like below

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
        grpc:
        http:

exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans"
    format: proto

  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

# Alternatively, use jaeger_thrift_http with the settings below. In this case
# update the list of exporters on the traces pipeline.
#
#  jaeger_thrift_http:
#    url: http://jaeger-all-in-one:14268/api/traces

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, jaeger, otlphttp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus, otlphttp]
```

##### Collector Debug logs

```
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    info    service/telemetry.go:104    Setting up own telemetry...
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    info    service/telemetry.go:127    Serving Prometheus metrics  {"address": ":8888", "level": "Basic"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    debug   extension/extension.go:135  Beta component. May change in the future.   {"kind": "extension", "name": "pprof"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    debug   extension/extension.go:135  Beta component. May change in the future.   {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    debug   extension/extension.go:135  Beta component. May change in the future.   {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.909Z    debug   exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:273    Beta component. May change in the future.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:273    Stable component.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "otlphttp"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    info    exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:275    Development component. May change in the future.    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    warn    loggingexporter@v0.78.2/factory.go:98   'loglevel' option is deprecated in favor of 'verbosity'. Set 'verbosity' to equivalent value to preserve behavior.  {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging", "loglevel": "debug", "equivalent verbosity level": "Detailed"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    info    exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:275    Development component. May change in the future.    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "logging"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   processor/processor.go:287  Stable component.   {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "metrics"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:273    Beta component. May change in the future.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "zipkin"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    info    exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:275    Deprecated component. Will be removed in future releases.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    warn    jaegerexporter@v0.78.0/factory.go:43    jaeger exporter is deprecated and will be removed in July 2023. See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/pull/2858 for more details.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   exporter@v0.78.2/exporter.go:273    Stable component.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "otlphttp"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   processor/processor.go:287  Stable component.   {"kind": "processor", "name": "batch", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   receiver@v0.78.2/receiver.go:294    Stable component.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.910Z    debug   receiver@v0.78.2/receiver.go:294    Stable component.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    service/service.go:131  Starting otelcol-contrib... {"Version": "0.78.0", "NumCPU": 4}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:30 Starting extensions...
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:33 Extension is starting...    {"kind": "extension", "name": "pprof"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    pprofextension@v0.78.0/pprofextension.go:60 Starting net/http/pprof server  {"kind": "extension", "name": "pprof", "config": {"TCPAddr":{"Endpoint":":1888"},"BlockProfileFraction":0,"MutexProfileFraction":0,"SaveToFile":""}}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:37 Extension started.  {"kind": "extension", "name": "pprof"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:33 Extension is starting...    {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    zpagesextension@v0.78.2/zpagesextension.go:53   Registered zPages span processor on tracer provider {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    zpagesextension@v0.78.2/zpagesextension.go:63   Registered Host's zPages    {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    zpagesextension@v0.78.2/zpagesextension.go:75   Starting zPages extension   {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages", "config": {"TCPAddr":{"Endpoint":":55679"}}}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:37 Extension started.  {"kind": "extension", "name": "zpages"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:33 Extension is starting...    {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    healthcheckextension@v0.78.0/healthcheckextension.go:34 Starting health_check extension {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check", "config": {"Endpoint":"0.0.0.0:13133","TLSSetting":null,"CORS":null,"Auth":null,"MaxRequestBodySize":0,"IncludeMetadata":false,"Path":"/","ResponseBody":null,"CheckCollectorPipeline":{"Enabled":false,"Interval":"5m","ExporterFailureThreshold":5}}}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    warn    internal/warning.go:40  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks    {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:37 Extension started.  {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    warn    internal/warning.go:40  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    warn    internal/warning.go:40  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] Server created   {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.911Z    info    otlpreceiver@v0.78.2/otlp.go:83 Starting GRPC server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4317"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    warn    internal/warning.go:40  Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "documentation": "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    otlpreceiver@v0.78.2/otlp.go:101    Starting HTTP server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "traces", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4318"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1 ListenSocket #2] ListenSocket created {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Channel created {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] original dial target is: "jaeger-all-in-one:14250"  {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] parsed dial target is: {Scheme:jaeger-all-in-one Authority: URL:{Scheme:jaeger-all-in-one Opaque:14250 User: Host: Path: RawPath: OmitHost:false ForceQuery:false RawQuery: Fragment: RawFragment:}}    {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] fallback to scheme "passthrough"    {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] parsed dial target is: {Scheme:passthrough Authority: URL:{Scheme:passthrough Opaque: User: Host: Path:/jaeger-all-in-one:14250 RawPath: OmitHost:false ForceQuery:false RawQuery: Fragment: RawFragment:}} {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Channel authority set to "jaeger-all-in-one:14250"  {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Resolver state updated: {
  "Addresses": [
    {
      "Addr": "jaeger-all-in-one:14250",
      "ServerName": "",
      "Attributes": null,
      "BalancerAttributes": null,
      "Type": 0,
      "Metadata": null
    }
  ],
  "ServiceConfig": null,
  "Attributes": null
} (resolver returned new addresses) {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"  {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] Subchannel created    {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING   {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING  {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] Subchannel picks a new address "jaeger-all-in-one:14250" to connect   {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.912Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0x4000cda078, {CONNECTING <nil>}  {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.913Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY   {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.914Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0x4000cda078, {READY <nil>}   {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.914Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Channel #3] Channel Connectivity change to READY    {"grpc_log": true}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.914Z    info    jaegerexporter@v0.78.0/exporter.go:173  State of the connection with the Jaeger Collector backend   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger", "state": "READY"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.914Z    info    healthcheck/handler.go:129  Health Check state change   {"kind": "extension", "name": "health_check", "status": "ready"}
2023-06-02T08:23:30.914Z    info    service/service.go:148  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
2023-06-02T08:23:35.806Z    debug   prometheusexporter@v0.78.0/collector.go:360 collect called  {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
2023-06-02T08:23:35.806Z    debug   prometheusexporter@v0.78.0/accumulator.go:268   Accumulator collect called  {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
```

I can only see `prometheus exporter` being called in debug calls and otlphttp exporter is not called at all.

### Edit 3

Configuration using port 4317

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
        grpc:
        http:

exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4317"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans"
    format: proto

  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

# Alternatively, use jaeger_thrift_http with the settings below. In this case
# update the list of exporters on the traces pipeline.
#
#  jaeger_thrift_http:
#    url: http://jaeger-all-in-one:14268/api/traces

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, jaeger, otlphttp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus, otlphttp]
```

Just for reference my exporter has following endpoints exposed..

```
http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics
http://localhost:4318/v1/logs
http://localhost:4318/v1/traces
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured both exporters (gRPC and HTTP) to use the same port:

```
otlp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
...
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
```

When you send a HTTP request to the gRPC endpoint, it fails. Remove the otlphttp exporter or set up the otlphttp receiver on port 4317.

Your configuration would then look like:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
        grpc:
        http:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4318"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4317"
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
      X-P-Stream: "demo"
      X-P-TAG-tag1: "value1"
      X-P-META-meta1: "value1"
      Content-type: "application/json"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans"
    format: proto

  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

# Alternatively, use jaeger_thrift_http with the settings below. In this case
# update the list of exporters on the traces pipeline.
#
#  jaeger_thrift_http:
#    url: http://jaeger-all-in-one:14268/api/traces

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin, jaeger, otlp, otlphttp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus, otlp, otlphttp]
```

Make sure to expose 4317 in docker-compose.yml as well.

Please try it out and let us know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Antoine, I have added edits in the question.

Comment: Wrong port. Use port 4317 for http.

Comment: Okay So now i started my http exporter at port `4317` and also updated collector`otlphttp` exporter configuration to use port 4317. still no requests going to exporter. I have added my configuration in question. What am I missing now :) ?

Comment: I wonder when I add my http exporter config under `otlp` exporter configuration, at least requests are hitting exporter though with the error `stream error: Request parse error: Invalid HTTP version specified` but requests are not hitting exporter when using my http exporter config under `otlphttp` configuration

Comment: Do I need to configure something extra to send the data to this `otlphttp` exporter exposed at port 4317 ?

Comment: You send data to receivers, and export data with exporters. The receivers section defines that you have both otlp and otlphttp receivers.